# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on Laravel Mix with vuetify-loader

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and I need to implement Vuetify in a Vue project. I also need vuetify-loader because otherwise I would need to import every Vuetify component manually.

The code I'm using in my `webpack.mix.js` file is the following:

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
        ]
    })
    .version();
```

Unfortunately, every time I try to compile by using `npm run dev` it gives me the following error: 
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was is in the vuetify-loader source code, on line 21 of loader.js:

```
path: this.resourcePath.substring(this.rootContext.length + 1),
```

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/blob/v1.4.3/lib/loader.js

vuetify-loader tries to read the length of `this.rootContext`.
I did a quick search online and I found, [on the webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/), that `rootContext` is a property of Webpack 4.

So I checked my webpack version and I found out that Laravel 5.6 is not using, by default, Webpack v4.

#### TL;DR;

All you have to do is upgrading your webpack version to Webpack 4 by doing so:

```
npm remove laravel-mix
npm install laravel-mix@^4.0.0 --save-dev
```